# C++ Expression Evaluation: What Happens "Under The Hood"?

Tags: c++, expression, evaluation, temporary

I'm still learning C++. I'm trying to understand how evaluation is carried out, in a rather step-by-step fashion. So using this simple example, an expression statement:

int x = 8 * 5 - 5;

This is what I *believe* happens. Please tell me how far off the mark I am:

1. The operands x, 8, 5, and 5 are "evaluated." Possibly, a temporary object is created to hold each value (I am not too sure about this).
2. 8 * 5 evaluates to 40, which is stored in a temporary.
3. 40 (temporary) - 5 evaluates to 35 (another temporary).
4. 35 is copied into x.
5. All temporary objects are destroyed in the reverse order they were created in (the value is discarded).

Am I at least close to being right?

Comment: From a very high level perspective, yes. In reality, the operations get carried out in CPU registers. And in real reality, the whole expression is evaluated at compile time, so all you end up compiling is "x=35".

Comment: Let me find the question to mark that one as duplicate...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you, sir. Hm. What would happen if all the operands were named objects, rather than literals? Would it create temporaries on the fly, so to speak, rather than at compile time?

Comment: In step 1 left Hand side x is not evaluated as it's not an operand.It would be an Operand only for a shortcut-operator like '+='

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you, sir. Hm. What would happen if all the operands were named objects, rather than literals? Would it create temporaries on the fly, so to speak, rather than at compile time?"

As Sam mentioned, you are on the right track on a high level.
In your first example it would use CPU registers to store temporaries (since they are not named objects), if they would be named objects it depends on the optimization flags that are set on the compiler and the complexity of the code as to how 'optimized' the code will be that is generated. you can take a look at the disassembly to really see what happens. for example if you do

```
a = 5;
b = 2;
c = a * b;
```

the compiler will try and generate the most optimal code, and since in this case there are 2 constants that are known at compile time, and you do a multiplication by 2, it will be able to take shortcuts, sometimes multiplications are replaced by bit operations which are cheaper (multiply by 2 is the same as shifting 1 to the left)

named variables have to live somewhere, either on the stack or heap, and the CPU will use the address of named objects to pass them around and perform functions on. (if they are small enough it will fit in registers and operate on them, otherwise it will start using memory, first the cache, and then bleed out to RAM)

You could google for 'abstract syntax tree' to get an idea of how readable c++ code is converted to machine code.

this is why it is important to learn about const correctness, aliasing and pointer vs references to make sure you give the compiler the best chance at generating optimal code for you. (aside from the advantages a user gets from that)